# How to map composite PK with FK NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to map something like this:

Table FOO: COMPOSITE PK: ID_OTHERFOOFK1 (PFK), ID_OTHERFOOFK2 (PFK), ID_FOO (PK)

Table OTHERFOO1 relation ship: OTHERFOO1 one to many FOO
Table OTHERFOO2 relation ship: OTHERFOO2 one to many FOO

How would the class look like? 
How would the hbm.xml look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Foo
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo1 Foo1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo2 Foo2 { get; set; }
}

class Foo1
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

class Foo2
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

<composite-id>
  <key-property name="id" column="ID_FOO"/>
  <key-many-to-one name="Foo1" column="ID_OTHERFOOFK1"/>
  <key-many-to-one name="Foo2" column="ID_OTHERFOOFK2"/>
</composite-id>
```

Comment: Thx ... only one little detail: synax key is pair tag.. <key-property name="id" column="ID_FOO"/> .. THx lot